# Display success message on Jqgrid EDIT form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, jqgrid

**EDIT PRMS**

```
edit: { 

addCaption: "Add CDM",
bSubmit: "Submit",
bCancel: "Cancel",  
bClose: "Close",
saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
bYes: "Yes",
bNo: "No",
bExit: "Cancel",

//serializeEditData: serailize,  
//editData: {new_CDM_ID: function() { return $('#cdmID').val();} },  
closeOnEscape: true,  
recreateForm: true,  
width: '450',  
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {  
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);  
return [result.success, result.message, result.id];
//return [success, message, new_id]  

}
```

**Question**

I'm able to capture error message in **afterSubmit** event and also able to display it on edit form of jqgrid. But same is not happeing for success message. I'm able to capture it but not able to display on edit form of jqgrid. Should i use a different event for displaying success message.

My requirements are:

1. Display error message in red (working)
2. Display success message in green (not working)

Comment: Any body got answer for this question?  
  
Just want to display success message in Jqgrid form editing

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) of the method "afterSubmit" say: *"(message is ignored if success is true). "*

You should use an hack. Place this code in your afterSubmit method.  :

```
if(response.status == 200){ 
      $(".topinfo").html("info message"); 
      var tinfoel = $(".tinfo").show();
      tinfoel.delay(3000).fadeOut();
      return [true,''];
} else {
      return [false,'error message'];
}
```

This works for the version of jqGrid 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just taking inspiration from @Gab, here is my final code that works great. closeAfterEdit if set true, above solution was not displaying msg, so i created new dialog.

```
function(response) { if(response.status == 200)                                                                             
{ 
        jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog("Info","<div class=\"ui-state-highlight\" style=\"padding:5px;\">Record updated!</div>", 
                                    jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:"right"});

        jQuery("#info_dialog").delay(3000).fadeOut();

        return [true,""];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
 afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
            var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+
                         '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                             'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                         "Done Successfully!!!"
                         '</div>',
                $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
                $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
                $infoTd.html(myInfo);
                $infoTr.show();
               setTimeout(function () {
                    $infoTd.children("div")
                        .fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            // Animation complete.
                              $infoTr.hide();
                        });
                }, 3000);
           // failcount = 0;
          //  totalcount = 0;
            return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
        },
```